# WhatsApp web won't stay online unless the application is open on device

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm using WhatsApp on my phone and desktop, and for some reason it has started booting me out of both unless I am in the phone application

Comment: If you go to "WhatsApp web" menu on your phone, can you see your PC listed in there?

Comment: iphone has the same problem, not android only

Answer (score 1):

Remove all Computer connected in your device and go through same process and now this time please check whether there is checkbox or not under QR Code
Similar to This

[image: Similar to This]

Comment: Well I don't think you should ever share a WhatsApp QR code publicly.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan if you know properly its entrance key for Whatsapp web, which helps to connect any whatsapp not a specific account or number of Whatsapp so it doesn't matter if you share publicly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it is meant to work. When it the app is minimised, it will run in background but won't show you as online. All messaging apps like allo, WhatsApp, hangouts do this. This is not a problem or a bug.

Comment: But it shouldn't kick you out of WhatsApp web if the app isn't in the foreground

Comment: exactly - it shows me as not connected on desktop until I go into whatsapp on the phone

Answer (score 0):

You have a setting in your phone that kills any closed app instead of keeping it in the background. I don't remember exactly how to find it and it probably varies with different phones, but it certainly the issues and not something wrong in WhatsApp app itself.

Comment: This setting is usually found on Developer Options as "Don't keep activities", but might vary depending on vendor/custom ROM

Answer (score 0):

keep me sign in never make WA destop open. so make sure to make whatsapp on phone always on/ force app to stay open. so WA destop will always open too

Comment: on phone - seting - permission - autostart - activated in the background - set on

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Samsung.  It seemed, interestingly, to be related to the fact that I didn't give it Phone and/or SMS permissions.  Once I enabled those (Settings -> Apps -> WhatsApp -> Permissions) the issue went away.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you have activated restricted data usage in Settings -> Data usage depends on phone.